# Django: limit models.ForeignKey results

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models, limit-choices-to

I have an order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True)
```

Which returns all possible profiles for an order, which is not necessary and slowing down the loading of the admin order page.

I want the profile returned to simply be the profile of the user who placed the order. I've tried changing it to:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'order': 99999})
```

which returns the correct profile for order number 99999, but how can I get this dynamically. The Order model is not aware of the 'self', but the order number is contained in the URL.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If the profile is fixed, it sounds like it shouldn't be editable at all. You could make it a [readonly field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), and set the value [when the order is placed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

Comment: Are you using the django admin?

Comment: Yes this is with the django admin site

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Django Admin, you can override the method `formfield_for_foreignkey` on your `ModelAdmin` class to modify the queryset for the profile field dinamically based on a GET parameter for instance (as you have access to `request` inside the method.

Look at this example from the docs (adapted for your case):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "profile":
            # You can get the order number from the GET parameter:
            # order = request.GET.get('order')
            # or a fixed number:
            order = '12345'
            kwargs["queryset"] = Profile.objects.filter(order=order)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Reference in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding the above code to my OrderAdmin class but this just results in a 504 Gateway Time-out...

Comment: Although it sort of works with the order = '12345' line, albeit with the wrong profile attached

Comment: Can you disable the debug, to see what Exception is being thrown that is causing the 504?

Answer (score 0):

I took another look at this and it seems to be working, although it seems like a bit of hack! The problem was that the order number doesn't seem to exist in the request so I am parsing the URL requested. I put this in my order admin:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "profile":
        try:
            order = int(filter(str.isdigit, str(request.path_info)))
        except:
            order = request.GET.get('order')
        kwargs["queryset"] = Profile.objects.filter(order=order)
    return super(OrderAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

The line that filters the url string for an integer works for the change order page of the admin, but didn't work for the order page overview, so I added the try/except. Any suggestions/improvements welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the context you're referring to the display on the Django Admin page. If you set 
    raw_id_fields = {'my_foreign_key'}

you will get a number, text description of related model (from **str**) and a nice popup box to open an instance of the admin page for your related models.

You could alternatively use 
    list_select_related = True 
to get the same behaivour you have now but with a couple of order of magnitudes lower number of queries.